# Using jQuery panzoom , the img dimensions stay the same when i click zoom , how to zoom it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery.panzoom

I was trying to put a small icon / marker inside a big background image, and I wish that background image can be pan while zooming and also having multiple zoom level.

So far what I tried is like this, my default division size is 1363 x 900 which shows in the Dev Tools. By default my marker is placed on the edge of the screen here, [default image without zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAhcx.png) Here is the screenshots 
[default div size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwC4Y.png) , after I click on the zoom functions of the panzoom , I saw that my image is get bigger , but i try to pan the marker into the edge of the image , it get stuck at the same x , y axis of my background image, [after zooming image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ3pE.png) , I found that inside my Dev Tools , the size of the div is still the same , [after zoom div size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixiEV.png) , how to change my div size also after I click on zoom ?? Is the panzoom causing the issues ??

The panzoom is from github , https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom , I am using this library.

This is the code how I do the panzoom and containment,

```
<body>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="zoom-out" onclick="zoomMinus()">-</button>
    <button class="zoom-in" onclick="zoomAdd()">+</button>
    <p id="zoomLevel">Zoom Level 1</p>
  </div>

  <section>
    <div id="panzoom" style="text-align: center;" class="panZoom">
      <img id="panzoomImg" src="{% static 'css/dist/img/photo4.jpg'%}" weight="1600" height="900"/>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div id="draggable1" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: orange;" class="parent">
      <div class="count"></div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="draggable" class="parent">
      <div class="padMargin">
        <!-- <div class="count"></div> -->
        <p class="counter" id="counter">10</p>
        <p class="counter1" id="counter1">20</p>
        <p class="counter2" id="counter2">30</p>
        <p class="counter3" id="counter3">40</p>
      </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

This is the jquery code :

```
 $('#draggable1').draggable({
    cursor: 'move', 
    containment: '#panzoomImg', 
    drag: function() {
      var cont = $('#panzoomImg').offset();
      var img = $(this).offset();
      var x = img.left - cont.left
      var y = img.top - cont.top
      $('#draggable1').text('x-axis :' + x + ', y-axis :' + y);
}});

$(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
      containment: "#panzoomImg",
      scroll: false,
    });
  });
```

Did I do the code wrong ? Or I need a specified jquery to add the size of the div also ?? Thanks in advance , please do tell me if I did not provide any sufficient information. Appreciate !!~